# Parse XSD restrictions

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, xsd, schema

```
    <xs:group name="datosGeneralesComunes">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="gravedad">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="4" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="zona">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="4" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="descripcion">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="2000" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tipo_accidente_salida">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="2" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tipo_accidente_colision">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="1" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="13" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="salida_via">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:enumeration value="0" />
                    <xs:enumeration value="1" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="tipo_accidente_animal">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:integer">
                    <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
                    <xs:maxInclusive value="27" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="unidad_demarcacion">
            <xs:simpleType>
                <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                    <xs:maxLength value="10" />
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

I need to parse the restrictions of a XSD file that are inside a group, but I can only see (in debug view) the name of the elements (I see "derived from restriction", too). But I need the minInclusive and maxInclusive values.

This is my code so far:

```
XmlSchema schema;

                        using (var reader = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "esquema.xsd")))
                        {
                            schema = XmlSchema.Read(reader, null);
                        }

                        XmlSchemaSet schemaSet = new XmlSchemaSet();
                        schemaSet.Add(schema);
                        schemaSet.Compile();
```

After compiling the schema and enter debug mode, I can't see what I need. Any clues?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's assume we want to get the 21th item of the schema (that's the case of my XSD snippet). Here are all the steps one by one (also I've included a dynamic printing instead of checking all the possible types of a restriction). Hope it helps to somebody in the future...

```
schema = schemaSet.Schemas().Cast<XmlSchema>().Single();
XmlSchemaGroup g = schema.Items[21] as XmlSchemaGroup;
XmlSchemaElement ge = g.Particle.Items[0] as XmlSchemaElement;
XmlSchemaSimpleType gef = ge.ElementSchemaType as XmlSchemaSimpleType;
XmlSchemaSimpleTypeContent gefc = gef.Content as XmlSchemaSimpleTypeContent;
XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction re = gefc as XmlSchemaSimpleTypeRestriction;
XmlSchemaObjectCollection fac = re.Facets;
foreach (var restriccion in fac)
{
    Console.WriteLine(restriccion.GetType().ToString()+": {0}", (restriccion as dynamic).Value);
    //if (restriccion.GetType().Equals(typeof(XmlSchemaLengthFacet)))
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("length: {0}", (restriccion as XmlSchemaLengthFacet).Value);
    //}
    //else if (restriccion.GetType().Equals(typeof(XmlSchemaMinInclusiveFacet)))
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("minInclusive: {0}", (restriccion as XmlSchemaMinInclusiveFacet).Value);
    //}
    //else if (restriccion.GetType().Equals(typeof(XmlSchemaMaxInclusiveFacet)))
    //{
    //    Console.WriteLine("maxInclusive: {0}", (restriccion as XmlSchemaMaxInclusiveFacet).Value);
    //}
}
```